# Saving QuickBlox chat history using JS

Tags: javascript, xml, chat, history, quickblox

i try to save chat history on server side by using JS. With no luck.

According to SDK i need to use extension: {save_to_history: 1}

But i don't understand where to use it, so XML request will be correct.

Here is an code from JS chat example:

```
message = {
            message: post,
            name: chatUser.name,
            avatar: chatUser.avatar,
            fb: chatUser.fbID
        };
        message = Strophe.escapeNode(JSON.stringify(message));

        if (userJID) {
            params = {
                to: userJID,
                from: connection.jid,
                type: 'chat'
            };
            connection.send($msg(params).c('body').t(message));
```

Plz advice!

Comment: Hello, i did try to add save_to_history: 1 to message{} and to params {} - the same results, XML request somehow showing "save_to_history", modified, probably because of some serialisation. and don't save anything.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of JS SDK:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript

Read the code snippets:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Chat_2.0_API_instead_the_chat_plugin

Next, use this:

```
QB.chat.send(userJID, {type: 'chat', body: post, extension: {
  save_to_history: 1,
  name: chatUser.name,
  avatar: chatUser.avatar,
  fb: chatUser.fbID
}});
```